# Why using insertBefore() to pull an element out of the friendly iframe doesn't work in IE7?

Tags: javascript, iframe, internet-explorer-7

I need to extract an element from the DOM tree of the iframe and put it into the DOM tree of the parent document.

This works with most modern browsers but not with IE7. It generates `Error: Invalid argument.`

### Test case

ie7test.html

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
        <div id="containerrrr">
                 <iframe id="iframe_element" src="ie7testiframe.html"></iframe>
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

ie7testiframe.html:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <div id="target_element">target</div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
var iframe_element = window.parent.document.getElementById("iframe_element");
var target_element = window.document.getElementById("target_element");
iframe_element.parentNode.insertBefore(target_element, iframe_element);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access and modify DOM before the document is "ready". While modern browsers handle a task like that with dignity (as long as the element referenced has already been parsed - your example is fine), attempting to manipulate an unclosed node in IE causes an error.

A commonly accepted way of dealing with this issue is *deferring* your scripts' execution until the document is ready to be manipulated; libraries like jQuery provide [syntactic sugar for such deferrals](http://api.jquery.com/ready/).

Comment: I wrapped the code into a setTimeout call with a 3 secs delay. No improvements.